# Git disappeared time to time

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, centos

I am developing with VS Code by connecting to a CentOS VM with SSH.

When I clone the repository there is no problem, but after sometime everything related to the git has disappeared.

I mean when I open VS Code I cannot see the branches, changes, anything that comes to your mind related to git.

I cannot pull/push it says (fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git).

Is there anyone who faced this issue before or any suggestion that will help me to solve this problem?

Comment: There is not enough information here to guess what the problem is, but there are two things I think are likely suspects: (1) you're using a "shared folder" inside this VM, and that is causing the problem. Shared folders and Git do not play well with each other, so don't do that. Or (2) you (or something on your system) is shutting the VM down abruptly, so that not all files get written out.

Comment: Yes @torek as you said there is not enough information, since I have searched over net before writing there and I could not find anything about it. I have set up a new VM yesterday and now I am using it carefully, after that I will see the problem better I hope, thank you for your help and ideas.

Comment: I have not still faced that will the problem. Will be updated later again.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have started VS Code from a folder which is not a Git repository. The folder that you cloned the repository into should have a `.git` folder present. This folder is what indicates that the parent folder is a Git repository. It is a hidden folder so you may have to enable a setting to allow you to see hidden files and folders before it will show up.

If you open VS Code from the folder that contains the `.git` folder then you should be able to push/pull etc.

Comment: Everytime I am opening it from the same folder in fact where the git folder resides. Sometimes the git is corrupted I think so it cannot access git and I have to clone the repository again.